# Induction/More so A question about simplifying square roots

Tags: induction

[image]

Ok I Get everything up until the point where it says. k $\sqrt{k+1}$ + $\sqrt{k+1}$ = (k+1) $\sqrt{k+1}$ How in the world did they get there? Or am I missing something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just factor out a $\sqrt{k+1}$ from the left hand side.  This yields $(k+1)\sqrt{k+1}$ which is what they claim.

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I didn't see that, thanks.

Comment: Happens to all of us.